# remove anything between angle bracket including it

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I have a very big text file `~ 105 G` it's includes a lot of `<XXXX>` (angle brackets including text in between).

I want to remove those brackets and text in between.

Comment: Is the file in fact an XML file?

Comment: Actually yes. @Kusalananda

Comment: Oops, actually not a dupe of that one.

Comment: I try this 'Removing text between two specific strings' but I want also the angle bracket to be removed not just in between @Sparhawk

Comment: The top answer there actually does remove the outer strings too, but the problem is that it will remove text *between* multiple sets of brackets too. (Hence my "oops".)

Answer (score 1):

"sed" is your friend. I am supposing there are no embedded brackets.

**Careful! this will overwrite your file.**

```
sed -i 's/<[^>]*>//g' big_file
```

Comment: doesn't work with me :(

Comment: what is not working? wrong output?

Answer (score 1):

Given an XML file and availability of [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
<tag attrib="hello">Hello world</tag>
<tag attrib="nice">Nice to see you</tag>
</root>
```

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v / file.xml

Hello world
Nice to see you
```

This uses XMLStarlet to extract the values of the root node and all of its child nodes.