# How to NOT show the tags?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, text-formatting, terminal-emulator

[image]

```
wadewayne@Cheetah:~$ man sdcv
wadewayne@Cheetah:~$ sdcv GNU
Found 28 items, similar to GNU.
-->McGraw-Hill Dictionary of Science and Technology
-->gnu

<BR><BR><b>VERTEBRATE ZOOLOGY</font></b><BR> Any of several large African antelopes of the genera <i>Connochaetes</i> and <i>Gorgon</i> having a large oxlike head with horns that characteristically curve downward and outward and then up, with the bases forming a frontal shield in older individuals.

-->Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary (En-En)
-->gnu


/ˈnuː/ noun, pl gnu or gnus [count]
: ↑wildebeest

-->Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th Ed. (En-En)
-->gnu


gnu /nuː/ BrE bre_gnu0205.wav AmE ame_gnu.wav noun (plural gnu or gnus) [countable]
[Date: 1700-1800; Language: Bushman; Origin: nqu]
 a large African animal with a tail and curved horns SYN wildebeest

-->Concise Oxford English Dictionary
-->gnu

<font color="#007000">noun</font> gnu<br>
[<font color=#009900>(g)nu:</font>, <FONT COLOR=#009900>(g)nju:</font>]<br>
<FONT face="Lucida Sans Unicode">■</FONT>  <FONT color="#990000">noun</FONT> a large African antelope with a long head, a beard and mane, and a sloping back. [Genus <FONT color="#990000">Connochaetes</FONT>: two species.] <BR> <BR><IMG src="D437C11D.bmp" align="absmiddle" width="46" height="16"><BR>C18: from Khoikhoi and San, perh. imitative of the sound made by the animal when alarmed.

-->Wikipedia English - Free Encyclopedia
-->Wildebeest

<DIV><div><dl><dd><i>For the <a href="bword://free%20software">free software</a> operating system, see <a href="bword://GNU">GNU</a>.</i></dd></dl> <br/>         <br/>   <i>Connochaetes taurinus</i><br/> <i>Connochaetes gnou</i><br/> <i>Connochaetes taurinus cooksoni</i><br/> <i>Connochaetes taurinus albojubatus</i><br/> <i>Connochaetes taurinus johnstoni</i><br/>  The <b>wildebeest</b>, also called <b>gnu</b> (<a href="bword://International%20Phonetic%20Alphabet%20for%20English">pronounced</a>  or ), is a large hooved (<a href="bword://ungulate">ungulate</a>) mammal of the <a href="bword://genus">genus</a> <i>Connochaetes</i>, which includes two species, both native to Africa: the Black Wildebeest (<i>C. gnou</i>), and the Blue &amp; White-bearded Wildebeest or Blue Wildebeest (<i>C. taurinus</i>).  The gnus belongs to the family <a href="bword://Bovidae">Bovidae</a>, which includes antelopes, cattle, goats, and other even-toed horned ungulates.</div></DIV>
<BR><TABLE><TR><TD width="40"><IMG src="BD681305.gif"/></TD><TD><A href="http://www.babylon.com/redirects/redir.cgi?type=wikipedia&full_url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildebeest">See more at Wikipedia.org...</A></TD></TR></TABLE>

-->Most Common Acronyms and Abbreviations
-->GNU

Gnu's Nearly Useless :-)&nbsp;<BR>Gnu's Not Unix&nbsp;<P><HR>&nbsp;<P>For more possible definitions for <STRONG>GNU</STRONG>, <A href='http://www.acronymfinder.com/af-query.asp?p=bc&acronym=GNU'>click here</A><BR>©1988-2002, All Rights Reserved, <A href='http://www.acronymfinder.com/'>AcronymFinder.com</A>

-->American Heritage Dictionary
-->gnu

<B>gnu</B> (n<IMG SRC='8B84B278.png' ALIGN='ABSBOTTOM' width='13' height='12'>, ny<IMG SRC='8B84B278.png' ALIGN='ABSBOTTOM' width='13' height='12'>)<BR><I>n.</I><BR>Either of two large African antelopes <I>(Connochaetes gnou</I> or <I>C. taurinus)</I> having a drooping mane and beard, a long tufted tail, and curved horns in both sexes. Also called <B>wildebeest</B>.<HR>[Probably from Dutch<TT> gnoe</TT>, from Xhosa<TT> i-ngu</TT>, <I>white-tailed gnu</I>, from San<TT> !nu</TT>, <I>black wildebeest</I>.]

-->Longman Pronunciation Dictionary 3rd Ed. (En-En)
-->gnu


gnu  BrE uk_gnu0205.wav AmE us_gnu.wav nuː njuː; ɡə ˈnuː, -ˈnjuː —The forms with ɡə- are jocular, as generally is the entire word. In serious discourse this animal is called a wildebeest.
▷ gnus nuːz njuːz; ɡə ˈnuːz, -ˈnjuːz

-->FOLDOC Computer Dictionary
-->GNU

<font color="#007000">noun</font><br>
&lt;<A href="bword://body">body</A>, <A href="bword://project">project</A>&gt; /g*noo/ 1. A <A href="BWORD://recursive acronym">recursive acronym</A>: "GNU's Not Unix!". The <A href="BWORD://Free Software Foundation">Free Software Foundation</A>'s project to provide a freely distributable replacement for <A href="BWORD://Unix">Unix</A>. The GNU Manifesto was published in the March 1985 issue of Dr. Dobb's Journal but the GNU project started a year and a half earlier when <A href="BWORD://Richard Stallman">Richard Stallman</A> was trying to get funding to work on his freely distributable editor, <A href="BWORD://Emacs">Emacs</A>.<BR><A href="BWORD://Emacs">Emacs</A> and the GNU <A href="BWORD://C">C</A> compiler, <A href="BWORD://gcc">gcc</A>, two tools designed for this project, have become very popular. GNU software is available from many <A href="BWORD://GNU archive site">GNU archive site</A>s.<BR>See also <A href="BWORD://Hurd">Hurd</A>.<BR>2. <PERSON> <A href="BWORD://John Gilmore">John Gilmore</A>.<BR>[<A href="BWORD://Jargon File">Jargon File</A>]<BR>(1997-04-12)<BR>

-->Microsoft Computer Dictionary
-->GNU

<FONT color='0080FF'>n.</FONT> Acronym for <FONT color='FF0000'>G</FONT>NU’s <FONT color='FF0000'>N</FONT>ot <FONT color='FF0000'>U</FONT>NIX. A collection of software based on the UNIX operating system maintained by the Free Software Foundation. GNU is distributed under the GNU General Public License, which requires that anyone who distributes GNU or a program based on GNU may charge only for distribution and support and must allow the user to modify and redistribute the code on the same terms. <FONT color='008000'> See also</FONT> <FONT color='0000FF'>Free Software Foundation</FONT>, <FONT color='0000FF'>General Public License</FONT>. <FONT color='008000'>Compare</FONT> <FONT color='0000FF'>Linux</FONT>.

-->MacMillan English Dictionary -American
-->gnu

gnu <font color="green" face="Lucida Sans Unicode"> / nu / </font> noun [count]<br>a WILDEBEEST<br>

-->wikt-en-en-2018-10-07
-->GNU

n.
Name of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free%20Software%20Foundation project to develop a free UNIX-like operating system, including the legal framework, such as the source code and documentation licenses.

-->Acronyms from A - Z
-->GNU

[1] GNU's Not Unix - Initiative zur Entwicklung einer freien Version von Unix der FSF nach der erfolgreichen Lizensierung durch AT&T <BR>[2] Goodnews Bay, AK, USA -internationale Fughafen-Kennung

-->Merriam-Webster Collegiate® Dictionary
-->wildebeest

<font color="#007000">noun</font> wil·de·beest<br>
<TABLE cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0"><TR valign="top"><TD nowrap="nowrap" style="vertical-align:top;">Pronunciation:    </TD><TD><B>'</B>wil-də-<FONT face="lucida sans unicode">ˌ</FONT>bēst</TD></TR> <TR valign="top"><TD nowrap="nowrap" style="vertical-align:top;">Function:          </TD><TD><I>noun</I></TD></TR> <TR valign="top"><TD nowrap="nowrap" style="vertical-align:top;">Inflected Form:   </TD><TD><I>plural</I> <B>wildebeests</B> <I>also</I> <B>wildebeest</B></TD></TR> <TR valign="top"><TD nowrap="nowrap" style="vertical-align:top;">Etymology:         </TD><TD>Afrikaans <I>wildebees,</I> from <I>wilde</I> wild + <I>bees</I> ox</TD></TR> <TR valign="top"><TD nowrap="nowrap" style="vertical-align:top;">Date:              </TD><TD>circa 1824</TD></TR></TABLE><BR><B>: </B>either of two large African antelopes (<I>Connochaetes gnou</I> and <I>C. taurinus</I>) with a head like that of an ox, short mane, long tail, and horns in both sexes that curve downward and outward ― called also <I>gnu</I>

-->CMU American English spelling
-->gnu

[nu:]

-->Merrian Webster 10th dictionary
-->gnu

noun
: either of two large African antelopes (Connochaetes gnou and C. taurinus) with a head like that of an ox, short mane, long tail, and horns in both sexes that curve downward and outward

-->Oxford Talking Dictionary
--><p>gnu

<B><FONT SIZE='+1'>gnu</FONT></B><BR>/<FONT face='Lucida Sans Unicode' color='Blue'>nu<FONT face='Ipa-samd Uclphon1 SILDoulosL'>:</FONT></FONT>, <FONT face='Lucida Sans Unicode' color='Blue'>ɲu<FONT face='Ipa-samd Uclphon1 SILDoulosL'>:</FONT></FONT>; <FONT face='Lucida Sans Unicode' color='Blue'>gn-</FONT>/<BR><I><FONT color='Teal'><FONT color='Green'>n.</FONT></FONT></I> <FONT SIZE='-2'>L18</FONT>. [f. Khoisan, prob. through Du. <I><FONT color='Teal'>gnoe</FONT></I>.] <S1>= <FONT SIZE='-2'>WILDEBEEST</FONT>.<FIELDSET><LEGEND>Quotation</LEGEND><FONT SIZE='-1'><B>brindled gnu</B> = <I><FONT color='Teal'>blue <FONT SIZE='-2'>WILDEBEEST</FONT></FONT></I>.</FONT><BR><FONT SIZE='-1'><B>white-tailed gnu</B> = <I><FONT color='Teal'>black <FONT SIZE='-2'>WILDEBEEST</FONT></FONT></I>.</FONT></FIELDSET>

-->Collins COBUILD Advanced Learner's English Dictionary
--><p>gnu

gnu gnus<BR><FONT color='#800000'>[N-COUNT]</FONT><BR> A <B>gnu</B> is a large African deer.<BR>

-->Columbia Encyclopedia
-->gnu

<TABLE ALIGN="CENTER" BORDER="0" WIDTH=95% CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="3"><TR><TD>(n<FONT FACE="MS Reference Sans Serif"></FONT>)   or <B>wildebeest</B> (wĭl´dəbēst´´)  , large African <A HREF="bword://antelope">antelope</A>, genus <I>Connochaetes.</I> Its heavy head and humped shoulders resemble those of a buffalo, while the compact hindquarters are like those of a horse. The gnu has a beard, a short, erect mane, and a long, flowing tail. Members of both sexes have large horns that curve down, outward, and up. Gnus are grazing animals and live in herds on open grassland. They constantly move in an effort to locate new pastures. The sight of a gnu migration, with its distinctive style of movement, is perhaps the most impressive group event in the animal kingdom. There are two species. The brindled gnu, or blue wildebeest (<I>Connochaetes taurinus</I>), is a large, fierce-looking animal of S and E Africa. It stands 41/2 ft (135 cm) high at the shoulder and weighs about 500 lb (225 kg); its coat is bluish-gray mottled with brown on the sides. The tail, mane, and beard are black. In the northern variety of this species (called the white-bearded gnu), which ranges as far N as Kenya, the beard is white. The brindled gnu lives in herds of 20 to several thousand individuals, often led by one or several old females and often found grazing with herds of zebra. Gnus are swift runners and herds engage in elaborate evasive maneuvers when threatened; their chief predator is the lion. They graze in the morning and evening, resting during the heat of the day; they often travel long distances in search of water. The white-tailed gnu, or black wildebeest (<I>C. gnou</I>), is a somewhat smaller animal once abundant in S Africa. It is now probably extinct in the wild, but is protected in parks and reserves, where its numbers are increasing. <I>Gnu</I> is the San (Bushman) term for these animals; <I>wildebeest</I> is Afrikaans. Gnus are classified in the phylum <A HREF="bword://Chordata">Chordata</A>, subphylum Vertebrata, class Mammalia, order Artiodactyla, family Bovidae.</TD></TR></TABLE>

-->Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary
-->gnu

<span style="font-size: medium;font-weight: bold;color : #005c9c;">gnu</span> <font face="Lucida Sans Unicode">/nuː/</font><br> <span style="font-size: small;color: #333333;">noun</span> <span style="font-size: small;color: #333333;">[C]</span> <span style="background: #eeeecc;border: 3px solid black;">plural</span> <span style="font-size: small;color: #333333;font-weight : bold;">gnu</span> or <span style="font-size: small;color: #333333;font-weight : bold;">gnus</span><br><span style="font-size: small;color: #000000;font-style : normal;">a large African animal with a long tail and horns that curve to the sides, which lives in areas covered with grass</span><br>

-->Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 8th Ed.
-->gnu


gnu  [gnu gnus] BrE  [nuː] z_gnu__gb_1.wav NAmE  [nuː] z_gnu__us_1.wav BrE  [njuː] z_gnu__gb_2.wav NAmE  [njuː] z_gnu__us_2.wav  noun (pl.  gnu or  gnus) =  ↑wildebeest

Word Origin:
 late 18th cent.: from  Khoikhoi  and  San, perhaps imitative of the sound made by the animal when alarmed. Khoikhoi and San are southern African languages. 

-->New Oxford English Dictionary
-->gnu

<span style="FONT-FACE: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT:bold;"><b>gnu</b></span>  <table><tr><td class="s1"> <span style="COLOR: red; font-weight:bold; size: 10pt;">noun</span> <df style="FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">a large dark antelope with a long head, a beard and mane, and a sloping back.</df> Also called <xr><a style="cursor:hand;" href="bword://WILDEBEEST"><span style="FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE: 7pt; TEXT-TRANSFORM: uppercase;">WILDEBEEST</span></a></xr>.<br><br><div class="tec">• Genus <i>Connochaetes</i>, family <txf>Bovidae</txf>: two species, in particular the abundant <ll>brindled gnu</ll> or blue wildebeest (<txb>C. taurinus</txb>).</div><br></td></tr></table><table><tr><td style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"><font face="Arial" style="size: 9pt; color: green"><b><i>ORIGIN</b></i></font> <d>late 18th cent.</d>: from Khoikhoi and San, perhaps imitative of the sound made by the animal when alarmed.</td></tr></table>

-->Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 7th
-->gnu

gnu<br>/   nuː; <i>NAmE </i>   ;    njuː; <i>NAmE </i>/<br> <font color="blue"><i>noun</i></font><br>(pl. gnu or gnus) = wildebeest<br><font color="#F14B35"><b>WORD ORIGIN</b></font><br>gnu<br> late 18th cent.: from Khoikhoi and San, perhaps imitative of the sound made by the animal when alarmed. Khoikhoi and San are southern African languages.<br>

-->The CMU Pronouncing Dictionary
-->gnu

'nu:

-->Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English
-->gnu

<span style="color: #0000D0"><b>gnu</b></span> /<span style="font-family: awlunicode; font-size: 110%">nuː</span>/ <i><span style="color: #000000"> noun</span></i> (<i>plural </i><b><span style="color: #0000D0">gnu</span></b><i> or</i> <b><span style="color: #0000D0">gnus</span></b>)<span style="color: #008500"> [countable]</span><BR>[<span style="color: #030303; font-weight: bold">Date: </span><span style="color: #303030">1700-1800</span>; <span style="color: #030303; font-weight: bold">Language: </span><span style="color: #303030">Bushman</span>; <span style="color: #030303; font-weight: bold">Origin: </span><span style="color: #303030">nqu</span>]<BR>a large African animal with a tail and curved horns<b><span style="color: #000060"> SYN </span></b><b>wildebeest</b>

-->The Oxford World Encyclopedia
-->gnu

(or <b>wildebeest</b>) A grazing antelope belonging to the same tribe (a taxonomic group below the subfamily) as the <A HREF="bword://hartebeest">hartebeest</A>. The two species of gnu are found on the African veld, where they are perhaps the fastest of the animals. The brindled gnu, <i>Connochaetes taurinus</i>, travels in herds of a dozen to several hundred individuals, frequenting the open plains in search of grass and a regular supply of water. Brindled in colour, it has brown stripes on the neck and shoulders, and a black tail; the horns are smooth and spread outwards. A single calf is born after a gestation period of eight and a half months. The white-tailed gnu, <i>C. gnou</i>, once common over much of the South African veld, is now restricted to reserves.

-->Britannica Pocket Encyclopedia
-->gnu

<font color="#007000">noun</font> gnu<br>
<BR><I>or <B>wildebeest</B></I><BR><BR>Either of two species of African <A href="bword://antelope">antelope</A> (genus <I>Connochaetes</I>).<BR><BR>The gnu stands higher at the shoulder than at the rump, reaching a shoulder height of 3–4 ft (1–1.3 m). The southern African form, the white-tailed gnu, or black wildebeest, is dark brown with long black tufts on the snout, chin, throat, and chest, and a black mane and flowing white tail. Today it exists only in national parks and preserves. The brindled gnu, or blue wildebeest, is reasonably abundant over much of central and South Africa. It is silvery gray with dark vertical bands on the sides and has a black mane, tail, and face, whitish cheeks, and a tuft of dark hair on chin and throat. Both sexes of both species have horns. Gnu live in often large, constantly moving herds and graze on the grasses and scrub of open plains.<BR><BR><IMG src="30A4098B.jpg" align="absmiddle" width="100" height="74"><BR>White-bearded gnu (<I>Connochaetes taurinus albojubatus</I>)<BR><BR>Leonard Lee Rue III

-->Computer Abbreviations v1.5
-->GNU

Gnu's Not Unix (operating system)

wadewayne@Cheetah:~$
```

Hi. I've installed [sdcv](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sdcv.1.en) yesterday.

But as you can see in the screenshot and code sample, it even shows the tags.
Is there any way to not get the tags?

Comment: Do you want to remove angle brackets and all text inside them?

Comment: Yes, sir, I want to remove the angle brackets and all the texts inside them. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove anything between angle bracket including it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462931/remove-anything-between-angle-bracket-including-it)

Comment: No, sir. This doesn't answer my question. :(

Comment: Why not? It does what you say you want, which is "_to remove the angle brackets and all the texts inside them_"